# Unable to deploy java project on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've created one project on Google App Engine and I'm unable to deploy the project with project id: "my project id"

Here are details of problem occurred:

The App Id you selected, "my project id", does not exist. Go to http://cloud.google.com/console to view existing App Ids or create a new App Id.

Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id="my project id"&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (project_id=u'my project id'). To create an App Engine application in this project, run "gcloud beta app create" in your console.

Is anyone facing this issue?

The old projects are working fine and I'm able to deploy those projects. The issue is only with newly created projects.

Comment: are you able to view your project in http://cloud.google.com/console ? `gcloud projects list` run this command and then check for your project in the returned list. If not, then you have to configure gcloud

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Yes, I'm able to see the project name in returned list.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to do exactly as the error message tells you, which is to run the [`gcloud app create`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/create) (beta no longer needed) command from a terminal.

App Engine is no longer automatically initialized for newly created projects, so you must run this command on a new project before deploying an App Engine app for the first time.

Comment: It works for me. For a new project, we've to follow this command and need to choose region before deployment. Thank you.

Comment: Why is this change not mentioned in the docs? I don't use gcloud. Any workaround?

Comment: You'll need to use the Cloud SDK if you want to use App Engine going forward. However as an alternative to 'gcloud beta app create' you can also go to the Cloud Console for a new project and click 'App Engine' to launch the new app creation flow which will accomplish the same thing.

Comment: New command for the same: gcloud beta app create --region "give region name listed"

Answer (score 0):

For my new eclipse project it seamed to work to create the new project at `https://console.cloud.google.com/` and wait 24 hours. At 'Activity' after the first listing of the new project `15.12.16 7:22 CreateProject` the next listing `<me@myhost> hat google.appengine.v1.Applications.CreateApplication für <myproject> ausgeführt 17. Dezember 2016 um 07:22:06 UTC+1` and more appeared automatically exactly after 24 hours. Then I was able to successfully deploy from eclipse.

For another new project Adams proposal worked fine: open the 'Google Cloud SDK Shell' as an administrator, 'cd' to the eclise workspace and my project and execute `gcloud beta app create`, choosing my preferred region and deploy my new project from eclipse.