# Google App Engine: This application does not exist

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I try to upload sample app to Google App Engine with existing progect ID.
Here is GAE screenshot
[gae screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O035U.png)

I'm using the same ID in the progect.
But when I try to upload it with plugin from Eclipse then I recive an error:

[eclipse error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/New3b.png)

The whole error from a console:

```
------------ Deploying frontend ------------

Preparing to deploy:
    Created staging directory at: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg2693799039714166602.tmp'
    Scanning for jsp files.
    Scanning files on local disk.
    Initiating update.
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=app1-152711&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (project_id=u'app1-152711'). To create an App Engine application in this project, run "gcloud beta app create" in your console.


Debugging information may be found in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\appengine-deploy7186088524405894873.log
```

Why I can not upload it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to deploy java project on Google App Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41179549/unable-to-deploy-java-project-on-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 4):

This is actually the new intended behavior. App Engine will not be enabled for new projects until you go through the app creation flow in the Cloud Console under 'App Engine' to enable the App Engine service, or alternatively run [`gcloud beta app create`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/app/create) from the console.

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered this myself. The project has to be created in the Cloud Console AND you need to go through the project setup in AppEngine. Something must be broken in the API that creates the AppEngine part of the process while uploading. So doing it through the web interface creates the project for you... and then uploading will essentially fill it in.

It never used to be this way, so maybe something changed.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. This is what I did to solve it.

Log in to your google cloud account. 
Select your project from the blue header bar.
Click the menu button(the 3 bars) on the top left of blue header bar.
Select IAM - you should permission for App Engine Service account. If not, you have to set it up.
To do that:
Click the menu button (the 3 bars) again
Click the App Engine
If you have not set it up, you will be prompt to do a tutorial.
Cancel the tutorial. 
Go back to IAM. 
Now you should see that the App Engine Service account added to the permission
Go ahead to upload. Should work now.

Comment: Nice work! You have to start the 'Your first app' section and pick the hosting region for the Service Account to be created. Cancel the next part, which is the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are logged in with the correct Gmail account. At the bottom right corner of Eclipse you will see which account you have authorized, or you will see "Sign in to Google" - click on it to authorize Eclipse.

Comment: да не, залогинился конечно. 
может из-за того, что у меня там несколько приложений? но ведь id правильный берется.

Comment: Адрес должен иметь привилегии "owner" или "developer". И можно попробовать выйти и заново зайти - если использовали gcloud, логин мог поменяться. ID, кстати, берется из appengine-web.xml файла.

Comment: I thought this was the problem initially... but it wasn't. See my answer from a few moment ago.