# "run "gcloud beta app create" in your console." - Can't type in console?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

When I try to "Deploy to App Engine" I get this error. (Picture below) I know something similar to this question has [been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41179549/unable-to-deploy-java-project-on-google-app-engine), but I can't figure out how to:

> run "gcloud beta app create" in your console.

I can't seem to type in the console.

Thanks!

[image]

**Edit**: This Console:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "I can't seem to type in the console."?

Comment: @JoshuaBriefman I edited the question to make it more clear. I can place my cursor in the console, but cannot type. (Is that the correct console?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not the right console.  You want to type that at the Windows 
command line.

Comment: Not to be blunt... but how do I do that? "'gcloud beta app create' is not recognized as an internal or external command."

Comment: https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/gcloud-python/latest/gcloud-python.pdf

Answer (score 2):

For opening google cloud shell console, go to the below link and click on >- icon at top right.

https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard?project=myproject-id

Once you get the console up, type "gcloud beta app create" to create an app engine application for this project. At the next step, it will also ask you to select the region.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! 

Note: replace 'myproject-id' at the end of the url with your actual project ID.